# On Mac - pyodbc doesn't fetch long columns from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-yosemite, pyodbc

I have the following python code running on top of mysql:

```
sql = "select col1 from table1"  
conn = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)  
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.execute(sql)  
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

The type of *col1* is LONGTEXT. If a row has *col1* longer than 255 characters it's not returned and *result* comes out empty, if it is shorter there will be no problem,  that is the following query for a "problematic" row will work as expected:

```
sql = "select substr(col1,1,255) from table1"
```

My OSX version is (Yosemite) 10.10.1 and I use mysql 5.3 UTF-8 driver - libmyodbc5w.so. If use the ANSI driver - libmyodbc5a.so - the row is fetched as expected.

Comment: Can you post the type of col1 in the table1?

Comment: Have you considered trying [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) to see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to work with the approached described above - using libmyodbc5a.so instead of libmyodbc5w.so, but then I hit a similar issue with Vertica connectivity via pyodbc, so I found the following issue:
https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=78

So resolution steps are:

- Download pyodbc source
- Edit src/getdata.cpp - you’ll notice the following block:

(around line 270)

```
case SQL_WCHAR:
case SQL_WVCHAR:
case SQL_WLONGVARCHAR:
    nTargetType = SQL_C_WCHAR;
break;
```

- Replace SQL_C_**W**CHAR with SQL_C_CHAR
- Rebuild pyodbc - issue should now be solved